# Positioning and Formatting Tkinter Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a user interface for a toolbox for image processing using Tkinter in Python.  I have a frame with a list and scrollbar to upload some files, and then I want to use a notebook with lists in order to upload additional files in different categories.  I can't get the positioning/formatting to look nice next to the first frame.  I've tried using the .grid function, but the notebook doesn't really fill the frame as I would expect.  How can I further define the size of the notebook and its placement to match the frame on the left?

```
def create_file_label(self):
         
        V1frame=ttk.Frame(self.master)
        V1frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=50)
        V1frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        V1_list = tk.Listbox(V1frame)
        V1_list.grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
        V1_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(V1frame)
        V1_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        
        V1_list.config(yscrollcommand = V1_scrollbar.set)
        V1_scrollbar.config(command = V1_list.yview)

        V2frame=ttk.Frame(self.master)
        V2frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=50)
        V2frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 2)
        #V2frame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  

        FVnotebook = ttk.Notebook(V2frame)
        FVnotebook.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=50)
        t1 = ttk.Frame(FVnotebook)
        FVnotebook.add(t1, text='Future Visit')

        FV_list = tk.Listbox(t1)
        FV_list.grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
        FV_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(t1)
        FV_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        
        FV_list.config(yscrollcommand=FV_scrollbar.set)
        FV_scrollbar.config(command = FV_list.yview)

        self.filelist=[V1_list, FV_list]
```

[image]

Comment: you could create minimal working code which we simply copy and run to test different settings.

Comment: first you could use backgrounds in different colors to see where are frames. Code doesn't show top frame `Future Visit(s) EMPTY` but maybe you should put `Notebook` in the same columns as `Future Visit(s) EMPTY`. OR maybe you should use correct values in `columnconfigure()` because you set weight for column `0` but you put `Notebook` in column `1`. Code `V2frame.columnconfigure()` doesn't defime how to put `V2frame` in main window but how to put `Notebook` inside `V2frame`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.